# I want to make related Time field with datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker

i want to make relation between the date field and the anther time field 
so when i select date it will give me valid time in this date to reservation and after i select start time it will give me end time in the thierd field it must be start time +30 min

HTML code is

```html
<div class="col-1-4 col-1-4-sm">
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="date" id="date" class="floatLabel form_date " name="arrive" >
                    <label for="arrive" class="label-date"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Day</label>
                    <input type="date" class="datetimepicker" id="Linked" value="" readonly>
                </div>


            </div>
            <div class="col-1-4 col-1-4-sm">
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="date" id="Start" class="floatLabel form_time" name="depart" />
                    <label for="depart" class="label-date"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;start time</label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-1-4 col-1-4-sm">
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="date" id="End" class="floatLabel" name="depart"  />
                    <label for="depart" class="label-date"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;end time</label>
                </div>
            </div>
```

JavaScript:

```js
var dateToday = new Date();

$(function () {
    
    $('.form_date').datetimepicker({
        //language:  'fr',
        format:'dd/mm/yyyy',
        //startDate: new date(),
        weekStart: 1,
        todayBtn:  1,
        autoclose: 1,
        startDate: dateToday,
        todayHighlight: 1,
        startView: 2,
        minView: 2,
        forceParse: 0,
        linkField: "Linked",
        linkFormat: "DD"
    });
    $('.form_time').datetimepicker({
        //language:  'fr',
        format:'H:ii p',
        weekStart: 1,
        todayBtn:  1,
        autoclose: 1,
        startDate: dateToday,
        startView: 1,
        minView: 0,
        maxView: 1,
        forceParse: 1,
        showMeridian: 1,
        minuteStep: 30,

        linkField: "End",
        linkFormat: "h:ii+30 p"

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Time ago I tried something similar and decided not to use *bootrap-datetimepicker* because it didn't fit my need. Y decided to use this [plugin](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) it is a little bit more flexible. Checkout the `onChangeDatetime` callback and the `allowedTimes` property. I'm not sure if the callback is triggered when both date and time has changed or when just one of them. May be it'd help to have date and time fields apart.

Comment: How can i do with this